# XML to XML converstion of Solr Stander Format using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, solr, solrj, solrcloud

This is my sample XML file for convert to a different format.Which i want to convert SOLR standered formate to upload xml file. i try to convert xml file using Xslt to solr format. but its only for working first section. i have to convert for all element. can i converted as my desired output. if any relative article please share.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<article>
<section xml:id="s495f">
    <title xml:id="h4cd0"> ID</title>
    <para xml:id="p75998"> User_name</para>
</section>
<section xml:id="s495f">
    <title xml:id="h4cd0"> ID</title>
    <para xml:id="p75998"> User_name</para>
    <para xml:id="pfa"> abbccddefg</para>
</section>
<section xml:id="s495f">
    <title xml:id="h4cd0"> ID</title>
    <para xml:id="p75998"> User_name</para>
    <para xml:id="pfa"> Test</para>
</section>
</article>
```

I try to convert to Solr Standered format using XSLT. Here is my XSLT file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 
 <xsl:template match="/article">
<add>
<doc>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
</doc>
</add>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para">
    <field name="para {@xml:id}">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </field>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <field name="title {@xml:id}">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </field>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my output like this: which are only for single "section" element, i try to convert for  every "section" element

**my output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<add>
 <add>
    <doc>
    <field name ="title h4cd0"> ID</field>
    <field name = "para p75998"> User_name</field>
    <field name = "para pfa"> xyxzzc</field>
    <field name = "para  p90f4b1"> location: details</field>
    <field name = "para p43cecf4"> Job profile</field>
    <field name = "para p75d4cc799"> refrence Id</field>
    <field name = "para p628c34"> True</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

my desired output:

```
<add>
    <doc>
    <field name ="title h4cd0"> ID</field>
    <field name = "para p75998"> User_name</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
    <field name ="title h4cd0"> ID</field>
    <field name = "para p75998"> User_name</field>
    <field name = "para pfa"> abbccddefg</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <field name ="title h4cd0"> ID</field>
        <field name = "para p75998"> User_name</field>
        <field name = "para pfa"> Test</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the Solr `doc` element in the template that matches `article`, but in fact you want to create a `doc` for every `section`. You need to create a template that matches `section` and move the `doc` element into it (the `article` template should create only the Solr `add` element).

NB spaces are not allowed in Solr field names. Try an underscore instead.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/article">
    <add>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
    </add>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <doc>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </doc>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para">
    <field name="para_{@xml:id}">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </field>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <field name="title_{@xml:id}">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </field>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can i use this xslt file in solrconfig?

Comment: Using the `UpdateRequestHandler`? Yes I would think so. https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-UsingXSLTtoTransformXMLIndexUpdates